# What is the behavior of git checkout with one file?

Tags: git, version-control, versioning, git-revert

If x and y were your files and you did a few commits like so:

```
commit 0: x / y
commit 1: x / y+1
commit 2: x+1/y+1
commit 3: x+1 / y+2 (HEAD)
```

If you did:

```
git checkout master~1 x
```

Would you get `x` or `x+1`?

Comment: I suppose you meant to say `git checkout HEAD~1 x` and not `master~1`. `master` is the default branch name and not a name of a commit.

Comment: @yasouser I imagine that is better practice, but it will work either way, as long as you are working in that branch. In this particular application, it will always be on master.

Comment: @yasouser `master` references the commit which is at the head of the `master` branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's stopping you from trying this to find out? Anyway, `master~1` refers to the commit before `master`. Assuming the `master` branch is at commit 3, you'll get the file `x` at commit 2, which is `x+1`.

Comment: Thanks. I was just working on other things and this wasn't a road block, just something to consider for down the line. I appreciate your answer.